# getting numeric keyboard default

Tags: android

How can I change android's default keyboard?
I want numeric keyboard to be shown first and then on clicking ABC in the numeric keyboard, I want to show alphabets keyboard.
Is that possible to implement?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a TextView for your text input, you simply need to set the inputMethod property.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputMethod

Comment: using inputMethod property we can only set numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069699/inputtype-of-edittext-in-android/5082343#5082343), I didn't find any answer to that except if you wrote your own keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the word "phone" in inputype property of your EDITTEXT

Answer (score 0):

Use **InputType**="**number**" in your **edittext**

Answer (score 0):

Just implement IME option on your numeric keyboard and once clicked change input type programmatically like this:

```
EditText editText= (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.et_awesome);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
   return true;
}
return false;
}
```

});

EditText on XML:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:imeActionLabel="ABC"
    android:imeActionId="666"
    android:inputType="number"/>
```